# add RadioButton with actionscript on stage

Tags: actionscript, radio-button

I know how to display a RadioButton with as2 on stage, no drag drop, using:

```
this.attachMovie(id,name,depth);
```

here 'id' is the linkage name in the library.
But the Problem is: i want to display RadioButton on stage without dragging it to the library.Then how can i enter 'id' in attachMovie? Or it can be set,how? Any alternative?